# Solr Exact match filtering

Tags: solr

I run Solr 5.3.1, field **firstname** has **firstnametype**

```
<fieldType name="firstnametype" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords-firstname.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Now, I want to query only records where **firstname** is "John Jepson", "John J" or just "John".

I've tried to add a filter:

```
fq=(firstname:"John Jepson" OR firstname:"John J" OR firstname:"John")
```

But result records contain "John Francis", "Avram John", "Frederich John" and so on in **firstname** together with correct records.

Is there a way to get rid of these wrong records without reindexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to reindex, and you'll have to have a field type made to produce the matches you want. If you're *only* interested in exact matches, case sensitive and all, using a `string` field will be fine (and then use a `copyField` instruction to copy the same content into both fields, so you don't have to modify your indexing code).

If you don't want the search to be case sensitive, use a TextField with a `KeywordTokenizer` and a `LowerCaseFilterFactory` as the only filter in the chain.

The reason why you'll have to reindex can be shown if you consider having indexed `John Jepson`. This text will have been broken into `John` and `Jepson` by your whitespace tokenizer. When you then issue a query with just `John`, Lucene will look for any document that has the token `John` present. Since your index side processing has created a separate token for `John`, it will match anything that has `John` somewhere in its name.

Comment: thanks! Also, I managed to remove a single wrong record (firstname:John Francis) by adjusting filter query to `(firstname:"John Jepson" OR firstname:"John J" OR (firstname:"John" -firstname:"John Francis"))` Maybe I can use rexexp, something like  `(firstname:"John Jepson" OR firstname:"John J" OR (firstname:"John" -firstname:/John\s+[A-Za-z]+/))`? I've tried this one, it didn't work

Comment: Regex-es are also evaluated against the tokens AFAIR, so that won't help much.

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: @Walter Fixed what?

Comment: @GennadiyKartashevskyy, I asking if he had solved his search issue